Same host for 2 activities but one with pathprefix : deeplinks in android
I have two activities in my Android app that share the same host but have different path configurations for deep links:
Activity A: Should handle deep links that contain only the host (e.g., https://example.com).
Activity B: Should handle deep links that include a specific path prefix (e.g., https://example.com/pathprefix).
Currently, both activities are being triggered because they share the same host and scheme. How can I configure my app so that:
Activity A opens when the deep link contains the host.
Activity B opens when the deep link contains the path prefix.
Rightnow I am getting two launcher, how can I redirect user to specific activity based the deeplink I receive?
Manifest :
 <activity
        android:name=".ActivityA"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DeeplinkDemoApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/pathprefix"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

